# Share class instance for other classes

Tags: python

### 1 - PROBLEM

How can I share a class instance between main script and other classes?
I need to initialize the class instance only once and use it everywhere.

I have an error like this:

> NameError: name 'logger' is not defined

### 2 - BACKGROUND

Here is my project structure:

```
project
|
|- classes
|   |   
|   |-loggerClass.py
|   |-workerClass.py
|
|-main.py
```

### 3 - THE CODE

Here is a simplified code I'm trying to build:

**loggerClass.py:**

```py
class loggerClass():
    def __init__(self):
        filename = os.path.join(PARAM['LOG_DIR'], datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'.log')
        self.logFile = open(filename, 'a')

    def write(self, message):
        line = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')+"\t" + message
        self.logFile.write(line)

    def __del__(self):
        print("============== CLOSE LOG FILE ===================")
        self.logFile.close()
```

**workerClass.py:**

```py
class workerClass():
    def __init__(self):
        global logger
        logger.write("Worker initiated")

    def doSomethingUseful():
        pass
```

**main.py:**

```py
from classes.workerClass import workerClass
from classes.loggerClass import loggerClass

logger = loggerClass()
worker = workerClass()

logger.write("END of the process") # I need to use the same "logger" instance everywhere
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use only one instance of `loggerClass`, than you do not even need to import `loggerClass` - import only the instance instead.

So, instead of having only `loggerClass` in module `loggerClass` and then doing this in `main`:

```
from classes.loggerClass import loggerClass
logger = loggerClass()
```

You should put line `logger = loggerClass()` inside `loggerClass` module and then do this in `main`:

```
from classes.loggerClass import logger
```

---

Alternatively, make a `get_logger()` function in the module, which always returns the same logger instance, if that coding style suits you better. Functionally, it would be the same.

---

BTW, the naming conventsions in your code are terrible. Do yourself a favour and read [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), specifically:

- don't name a class `loggerClass` - name it `Logger`
- worse than that: don't name a module `loggerClass` - name it e.g. `logger` if there is no better name
- don't name a package `classes`, because it is simply a bad name

Comment: If you do this, **do not** attempt to reassign `logger` anywhere in the program. You have a zillion different `logger` variables referring to the same instance, not one shared `logger` variable. Reassignment will not affect all those variables; it will usually only affect one, but may affect an unpredictable subset depending on import order.

Comment: Thanks @zvone! I'll try it. I'll do my best with naming conventsion :)

Comment: Yes, @user2357112 I agree. Good comment!